# Having problems registering and using a 64-bit C++ written ATL dynamic library

Tags: c++, .net, dll, regsvr32

I am having issues registering and using a dynamic library under Windows 7 x64, the 64-bit version of dll compiles but the compiler log outputs:

> **`Error   MSB3073:    The command "RegSvr32 /S "...\x64\Debug\xxxxx.dll" exited with code 3.`**

But, when I build 32-bit version of the dll, compiler log outputs the RegSvr32 command was successful.

I already set the `Linker >> General >> Register Output` to `No` in both x86 and x64 build configurations.

I tried running 64-bit and 32-bit version of RegSvr32 (without silent mode) with 64-bit dll, but it responds with the following error:

> **`The module "xxxxx.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. The specified module could not be found.`**

I checked it using dependency walker and it reported more than 100 dlls are missing so, I cannot show them here. Some of them are:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL
...
WLANUTIL.DLL
WLDAP32.DLL
WTSAPI32.DLL
XMLLITE.DLL
```

Dependency Walker with opened dll:

[image: Dependency Walker with opened dll]

I am wondering what the reason for only 64-bit version of dll cannot register using RegSvr32.

Any help is greatly appreciated to resolve this issue.

**UPDATE 1**

Trying to running the application with this dynamic library results in the following error (both 32-bit and 64-bit versions) :

> **`The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`**

All redistributable packages currently I have installed:

[image: Redistributables those already installed]

Is there any visual c++ redistributables I have to install to solve this?

**UPDATE 2**

I found More information on `api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186421(v=vs.85).aspx) and tried linking `WindowsApp.lib` with this dynamic library, but it even didn't resolve the issue.

**UPDATE 3**

I ran system file checker and it gave me following output as I thought it should:

> **`Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by removing `mincore.lib` from linked `.lib` files in both x86 and x64 versions of project, which I recently linked to use `GetFileVersionInfoSize` API function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into the project properties of the DLL you're trying to register
2. Go to Configuration Properties >> Debugging
3. Under "Command", click on the little down arrow and choose "regsvr32.exe"
4. Under "Command Arguments" type "$(TargetName)"
5. Put a breakpoint somewhere in your DLLMain
6. Now Debug the DLL (Right click on the dll project in solution explorer and choose "Debug")

If you get to your DLL main, you can debug from there until it fails.  If you do not, you should take a look at the output window to see any relevant messages.  You might need to change your output window filters too.  Right Click on the output window and check all categories of messages to be sure it gives you everything and then debug again.

That should at least tell you where you are failing.  Look for module load failures and the like

Edited to add - you might try just changing the build step by removing the "/S".  That is "Silent" mode and in this case you want to see the messages.

Comment: I tried what you said but I didn't resolve the issue. There's nothing wrong in DLLMain I think.